# Htaccess: How to get Variable form URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do have a question regarding htaccess. I am trying to do the following:

`blabla.com/lala` and `blabla.com/lulu`

lala and lulu are my variables (showing different content on both sites, but it is the same file (example.php).

So what I did in htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^&]+)$ example.php?type=$1
```

But when echoing GET[type] I just get the filename("example.php"). But I want it to show "lala" or "lulu".

It works when I do it like that:

```
RewriteRule ^blablabla/([^&]+)$ example.php?type=$1
```

But I just don't need "blablabla" :D

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using [L] is definitly what you need

Answer (score 3):

> But when echoing GET[type] I just get the filename("example.php"). But I want it to show "lala" or "lulu".

This is because rewrite rules loop until the URI going into the rewrite engine is the same one that comes out of the engine. Your regex `^([^&]+)$` is matching the target of your rule (`example.php`). So you either need conditions to check if the URI isn't already `example.php` or you check if the request points to a file or directory that doesn't exist:

```
RerwiteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/example\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ example.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ example.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi,I tried "RewriteRule ^(.+)$ example.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]". It does work on example.php. But its destroying other pages on the page where I already used it. I already used the following on top of the htaccess: "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$"

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ example.php?type=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Nope, `A-Za-z0-9-` would select `example`

Comment: Also URI's sent through rules in htaccess files have the leading slash stripped off

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` for query string rewrite